# Calling a Python C extension blocks all Django processes/users

Tags: python, c, django, multithreading

### Problem

I have written a Python C extension (`ftaCalculate`) in order to improve the performance of a given function that was previously written in pure Python. I have been able to increase the execution speed by a factor of x10, so no problem on this site.

```
import ftaCalculate

cs_min = ftaCalculate.mcs(N, tree)
```

However, I am executing this function in a Django framework. The problem is that, until the function `ftaCalculate.mcs` does not finish, I cannot do anything on my website. When the function was in Python, I could press other buttons and access other URLs.

This is specially a problem when several users are working at the same time in the website, because the other users cannot do anything while this function is being executed.

Actually, you can see in the following image that one core is at 100% when running the function:

[image]

### Question

Do you know any way I could call my Python C extension without "freezing" the Django framework?

### Possible workaround

In the worst case, I could try calling this part of the code with [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html). However, I would prefer another solution, since I do not need Celery when running in pure Python.

Comment: I believe this is due to the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). Only one Python instruction can execute at one time. Normally this is pretty much ok because it can switch "threads" between instructions, giving the impression of multitasking. However, the call to your C code will count as a single instruction, holding the GIL for the entire duration. You could perhaps look into solutions like the multiprocessing module, though I don't have a lot of experience there.

Comment: How are you running Django itself? Are you running it through a webserver like Apache or Nginx?

Comment: Yes, I am running Django with Nginx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Kemp suggested, the problem was on the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). The solution has been to release the GIL when I am not using any Python object and reacquire it afterwards.

Following the details of [Releasing the GIL from extension code section](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#releasing-the-gil-from-extension-code), I have put the corresponding C code between the following two lines:

```
Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
... Code dealing only with C objects ...
Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
```

This allows to call other processes within Django while the function is being executed.